# Using Gmail API in Chrome Extension without Identity API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I have a Chrome extension that uses the [Gmail REST API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) to send emails on behalf of the user. This API requires an Oauth2 token, which I'm retrieving using `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`.

### The Problem

However, I am running into some issues with the Chrome Identity API. In particular, if the user authenticates with `chrome.identity` with a different Gmail account then the one they're signed into Chrome with, then they are prompted to re-login every hour or so (which doesn't happen if the accounts are the same). In addition, I'd like to minimize the number of permissions my extension asks for as a general principle (permissions sometimes introduce warning messages on install and risk disabling existing users on update), so I'd like to not have to ask for the "identity" permission if I can avoid it.

### My Question

**How can I authenticate the Gmail API in Chrome Extensions without using the Identity API?**

### Current Progress

I initially tried using Google's Javascript Client for auth, but that seems to be [incompatible](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/64) with Chrome extensions. After having searched other SO issues and some [Google materials](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth), it seems that the Identity API is indeed the recommended auth solution in Chrome Extensions. However, for the UX reasons mentioned above, I'm finding this solution problematic. And I do think an alternative should be possible -- for example, the MixMax Chrome extension, which uses the Gmail API, does not ask for the Identity permission.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Inspect the source code of those extensions. They may be manipulating cookies on API requests via webRequest API or some other method.

Comment: I can use any Google API within a chrome extension through a [gapi client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

Comment: @ziganotschka Could you explain how you were able to get the gapi client working -- if I could get that it would solve my problem. Do you run the client in the content script or background script? Does the client load on every site, or just certain sites? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to load the gapi client libraries. The easiest way to do it is to implement it in an html file -if you have a pop-up incorporated. But can be also done from background with a content script. Once you have the libraries, you build and use the client just in the same way as in the Google APi quickstarts for browser.